# Dynamic virtual attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My Model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :lack_knowledge_points, :through => :knowledge_point_infos,
:conditions => ['knowledge_point_infos.level <= ?',10],:source => :knowledge_point
```

I want that `10` be dynamic

What is my best practice?

Define a method and find_by_sql? Or can Rails do something else for me?

Comment: you can use scopes with lambda syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear how you want 'level' to be dynamic. Anyway, you could use scope with lambda or define a method in the model.

```
#If you want it to return an array
def lack_knowledge_points(threshold)
  knowledge_point_infos.where('level <= ?', threshold).map{|info|info.knowledge_point}
end
```

Comment: Not tried
but I find something looks the same with you :http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/

thanks for helping